# Wordpress: Remove Bullets from Navigation

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation

I am looking for a solution to remove the bullets from my main menu here on my test page.

You have to scroll to second page so that you can see the main navigation at the top. My problem is that I want to remove the bullets between the links. So right now it is HOME (bullet) LOKAL but I want it to be HOME  LOKAL!

I know the CSS for that is:
list-style: none; OR list-style-type: none; and I entered this line of code but it is still not working. I know it may be a custom question but maybe some other guys using the same template and also want to remove those bullets at the navigation bar.

The wordpress theme is called: "Brooklyn"

I would really appreciate if someone can help me. I am searching for hours now through my CSS files from that theme.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: when i did inspect element in safari, the console popped up with these warnings: https://mega.nz/#!1ocljACA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `#navigation ul li a::after` in http://projekt85.ccsolution.at/wp-content/themes/brooklyn/style.css has property `content: "•";`

Remove content property from the style.css and it will work.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your awesome and fast help!